# Find us on social networks

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Social networks are a great way to get the word out about our site, and hopefully attract some more interest. To that end, I've setup a Facebook page for us here:

**http://www.facebook.com/arduino.se**

If you're an FB user, please like and share the page, and feel free to make suggestions about what we do with it. The page belongs to all of us, although for obvious practical reasons only the moderators will have direct admin rights on it.

To get us started, I've already setup an event on it for our upcoming Project Showcase event.

Please also feel free to suggest other ways we could represent/promote the site on other social media.

Answer (score 4):

There's an [Arduino community on Google+](https://plus.google.com/communities/114444064583962076057). It's not specifically for us, but it is a general Arduino page. Some people also ask programming questions on there, and I think it would be a good idea to **point them to our site,** maybe even asking a question for them and showing them a link later.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the Arduino SE Twitter, @StackArduino: https://twitter.com/StackArduino. It doesn't have have any tweets yet, though.